# DatabaseFirst EntityFramework: format value automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have my EfModel.cs autogenerated.

```
public partial class EfModel
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTime { get; set; }

}
```

This EfModel.cs is in a library and used by different applications.

- One application cares about the date and time of the DateTime
- Another application only cares about the date

Is there a way for me to keep it as an EfModel object the application but format the DateTime as needed by the application? I do not want to create a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not something your model (the EF classes) should be worrying about, they're just a relatively dumb cache of your physical database.

Your controllers shouldn't need to worry about it either, they should be working with the managed date class as it is.

It's just your view that decides how that value is ultimately displayed. That's where your view-specific code should be going anyway, whether it's in the same application or in multiple ones.

Comment: This is the best answer but if you really need to have those properties you can add 2 properties not mapped (use NotMappedAttribute) that use DateTime as backing field.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date in your application however you like. Keep the full date in your model and then only show the parts or using the format of your choice.

Take a look at this article for different date formats:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx